# how to test a subroutine which has 'exit' in it (perl)

Tags: perl, unit-testing

For example:

dummy_mod.pl

```
package Dummy::Mod;

use warnings;
use strict;

sub print_and_exit {
    print "Hello World\n";
    exit;
}
1;
```

dummy_mod.t

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::More;
use Test::Output;

plan tests => 2;
ok(require('dummy_mod.pl'), 'load test') or exit;
stdout_is(sub { Dummy::Mod->print_and_exit() }, "Hello World\n", "stdout test");
```

Then I got:

```
$ perl dummy_mod.t
1..2
ok 1 - load test
# Looks like you planned 2 tests but ran 1.
```

So seems the test script exit before test #2 finish. If I remove '**exit**' from **print_and_exit** subroutine, it can work, but I don't want to do that in my real case. I've tried with:

```
stdout_is(sub { local $SIG{INT} = sub {}; Dummy::Mod->print_and_exit() }, "Hello World\n", "stdout test");
```

it doesn't work either.

Edit: The main purpose is testing the output from that subroutine, actually I don't care much about the exit code from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Test::Trap`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Trap). Here's the example from the synopsis in the documentation:

```
use Test::More;
use Test::Trap;

my @r = trap { some_code(@some_parameters) };
is ( $trap->exit, 1, 'Expecting &some_code to exit with 1' );
is ( $trap->stdout, '', 'Expecting no STDOUT' );
```

Note that `Test::Trap` does more than just trap the exit; you can also use it to test `STDOUT`, `STDERR`, warnings, and more.

Comment: Thanks, it works with: is ( $trap->stdout, "Hello World\n", 'stdout test' );